# How do I fail the CI when there is an `@tag` in a test?

Tags: continuous-integration, elixir, ex-unit

We often have comments in our code review that tells people to remove their `@tag` from tests they had tagged to have a tighter iteration loop. However, I think that is a waste to have depend on humans to make those comments.

Is there some option for `mix test`, `credo` or some other tool that exists to detect `@tag` in tests?

Comment: I would start this exploration by first identifying with objective evidence (i.e. a profiler) that the tags are really causing performance problems.  I suspect they have no impact at all.

Comment: It's not performance that I care about, it's the noise. Having the tests littered with tags is like having your code littered with one line useless comments. That's obviously subjective, but it's definitely how I feel.

Comment: You have to decide which cost is greater: the noise introduced by the @tags or the labor involved in removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this bash spell:

```
! grep -R --include="*.exs" "@tag" test
```

It basically greps for all instances of the pattern `@tag` in the directory `test` (because of the `-R`). The `!` negates the exit code, so it succeeds when `grep` finds nothing and fails if it finds something. Most CIs should fail when any command in the script fails, so this might suit your bill.

Comment: That's dope. I ended up doing something very similar.
`
function check_for_tags {
        tags=\`rg "@tag" -g apps/**/*.exs | wc | awk '{print $1}'\`
        if [ $tags -ne "0" ]; then
                echo "Your tests contain tags"
                return 1;
        fi
        return 0;
}

`

Comment: @CallMeNorm then please mark this answer as solving the issue.